# how to pass UIColor object from one class to another class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the code below, and I wants to pass the selected color to another class, but it gives me the following warning and does not work:

> incompatible pointer types assigning to nsstring from uicolor strong:

**Code:**

```
-(IBAction)showpickerview
{
    NEOColorPickerViewController *controller = [[NEOColorPickerViewController alloc] init];
    controller.delegate = self;
    //controller.selectedColor = self.currentColor;
    controller.title = @"Select Color";
    UINavigationController* navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];

    [self presentViewController:navVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)colorPickerViewController:(NEOColorPickerBaseViewController *)controller didSelectColor:(UIColor *)color 
{
    SecondClass *second = [[SecondClass alloc]init];
    second.selectColor = color;
    NSLog(@"selected color %@",second.selectColor);

    //UIColor *color1 = color;
    //const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);
    //second.selectColor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f,%f,%f", components[0], components[1], components[2], components[3]];
    //NSLog(@"selected color %@",second.selectColor);

    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: how do you invoke colorPickerViewController??

Comment: incompatible pointer types assigning to nsstring from uicolor strong

Comment: this is delegate method auto cal actualy i am using this libarary u may visit this link https://github.com/kartech/colorpicker

Comment: There you have it `incompatible pointer types assigning to nsstring from uicolor strong`:)

Comment: yes i have this warning

Comment: Your selected color is a NSStirng in SecondClass make it UIColor

Answer (score 1):

Alternative 1:

```
- (void)colorPickerViewController:(NEOColorPickerBaseViewController *)controller didSelectColor:(UIColor *)color 
{
 SecondClass *second = [[SecondClass alloc]init];
 second.selectColor = controller. selectedColor; 
 NSLog(@"selected color %@",second.selectColor);

[controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

Since NEOColorPickerBaseViewController is an instance of NEOColorPickerViewController this should work.

Alternative 2:

It seems to be that your selected color in SecondClass is a NSString instead of UIColor. So you are getting that warning.

Comment: yes i was using nsstring instead of uicolor but stil the selectedColor is not appling on UIView

Comment: How do you apply color to SecondClass ?

Comment: second.view.backgroundColor = selectedColor ??